# Japanese keyboard on my ADB Android

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

I cannot test my application because I have the keyboard set with a Japanese / Chinese configuration for the keyboard...

[image]

Thanks for helping me !!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In AVD, Setting->Language and Keyboard Setting->Text Setting and Unchecked all japanese/chinese setting.

I hope this help.....